# How to show mat-grid inside mat-menu as responsive

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have material grid and menu .I use mat-menu like tooltip,there will be other grids below and each of them have this mat-menu.When user clicks it,user should see appeared box and whats inside.I decided to use Mat-Grid inside but it isn't being responsible as usual it is.Mat-grid is flex and skrinking due to user's action as protecting its position.Thats what I want.But mat-grid here isn't getting smaller as big mat-grid does when you change the page width.

StackBlitz Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-bootstrap-css-zcjddn?file=src/app/app.component.html

That looks well when page is orginal size(PC,Laptop etc)
[image]

Here that problem exists below(Width for tablet , mobile etc.Not getting smaller like grid on the outside)

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gMki.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
HTML:

    <mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="2:0.5 (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
    <`enter code here`mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>5</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>6</mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

.ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.breakpoint = (window.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1 : 6;
}

onResize(event) {
this.breakpoint = (event.target.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1 : 6;
}
```

[Check Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-mat-grid)

Comment: I checked.But this isn't what I'm looking for.This just changes the orientation of allignment as column from row after width changes.But I want them being shrinked when width getting smaller.If I'm wrong please could you edit my stackblitz and share?

Comment: I have changed in your code please check 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-bootstrap-css-zcjddn

Comment: I checked but this isn't even as expected.Look that menu isn't being opened compeletely